# Where should I place 'require gem'? What file in my Rails application should it go in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using the 'fastimage' gem and I'm not sure where to place the require 'fastimage' statement in my Rails application. What is the best practice for writing require statements? Where can I place it so that I can use the FastImage methods anywhere in my application?

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that was a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include in in your Gemfile. After that, run `bundle install`. You do not need to type `require` since that is already handled for you. Do note that you need to restart the rails server in order for your app to include your gem.